# Failed to set remote answer sdp on Safari

Tags: safari, webrtc

I'm using Safari `11.0.3 (13604.5.6)` and when I `setRemoteDescription` I get the following error:

> Failed to set remote answer sdp: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set remote video description send parameters.

Here is my sdp:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=VidyoWebRtcServer
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS Video1 Video2 Video3 Video4 Video5 Video6 Share0
m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 0 8
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:cBvX
a=ice-pwd:MaSZuPYUZT8yMk2HrcWWrc
a=fingerprint:sha-256 22:8C:63:2C:02:75:DC:95:51:96:5C:63:94:A0:E7:B8:59:59:70:B1:7A:82:BA:C5:6D:4E:83:38:DE:13:31:3C
a=sendrecv
a=mid:audio
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000/2
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000/2
a=maxptime:60
a=ssrc:10001 cname:Video1
a=ssrc:10001 msid:Video1 AudioLabel1
a=ssrc:10001 mslabel:Video1
a=ssrc:10001 label:AudioLabel1
a=ssrc:10002 cname:Video2
a=ssrc:10002 msid:Video2 AudioLabel2
a=ssrc:10002 mslabel:Video2
a=ssrc:10002 label:AudioLabel2
a=ssrc:10003 cname:Video3
a=ssrc:10003 msid:Video3 AudioLabel3
a=ssrc:10003 mslabel:Video3
a=ssrc:10003 label:AudioLabel3
a=ssrc:10004 cname:Video4
a=ssrc:10004 msid:Video4 AudioLabel4
a=ssrc:10004 mslabel:Video4
a=ssrc:10004 label:AudioLabel4
a=ssrc:10005 cname:Video5
a=ssrc:10005 msid:Video5 AudioLabel5
a=ssrc:10005 mslabel:Video5
a=ssrc:10005 label:AudioLabel5
a=ssrc:10006 cname:Video6
a=ssrc:10006 msid:Video6 AudioLabel6
a=ssrc:10006 mslabel:Video6
a=ssrc:10006 label:AudioLabel6
m=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 96 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:cBvX
a=ice-pwd:MaSZuPYUZT8yMk2HrcWWrc
a=fingerprint:sha-256 22:8C:63:2C:02:75:DC:95:51:96:5C:63:94:A0:E7:B8:59:59:70:B1:7A:82:BA:C5:6D:4E:83:38:DE:13:31:3C
a=sendrecv
a=mid:video
b=AS:1536
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:96 red/90000
a=rtpmap:98 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc:50000 cname:Share0
a=ssrc:50000 msid:Share0 ShareLabel0
a=ssrc:50000 mslabel:Share0
a=ssrc:50000 label:ShareLabel0
a=ssrc:50001 cname:Video1
a=ssrc:50001 msid:Video1 VideoLabel1
a=ssrc:50001 mslabel:Video1
a=ssrc:50001 label:VideoLabel1
a=ssrc:50002 cname:Video2
a=ssrc:50002 msid:Video2 VideoLabel2
a=ssrc:50002 mslabel:Video2
a=ssrc:50002 label:VideoLabel2
a=ssrc:50003 cname:Video3
a=ssrc:50003 msid:Video3 VideoLabel3
a=ssrc:50003 mslabel:Video3
a=ssrc:50003 label:VideoLabel3
a=ssrc:50004 cname:Video4
a=ssrc:50004 msid:Video4 VideoLabel4
a=ssrc:50004 mslabel:Video4
a=ssrc:50004 label:VideoLabel4
a=ssrc:50005 cname:Video5
a=ssrc:50005 msid:Video5 VideoLabel5
a=ssrc:50005 mslabel:Video5
a=ssrc:50005 label:VideoLabel5
a=ssrc:50006 cname:Video6
a=ssrc:50006 msid:Video6 VideoLabel6
a=ssrc:50006 mslabel:Video6
a
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the video m= line does not contain any actual codecs, only ulpfec and red. This is most likely due to Safari not supporting VP8 despite being mandatory to implement in WebRTC. I would bet the vidyo support has some words on safari compability.